# Validación de un formulario con Jquery: con input type button no hace nada; Con el type submit funciona

Tags: jquery

**cuál seria el problema ya que no esta entrando al darle click al botón tipo button, y con el botón tipo submit si funciona, estoy tratando de solucionarlo más no lo e conseguido, este es mi código de antemano gracias. **

```
$(function(){
          $.validator.addMethod("alfanumOespacio", function(value, element) {
         **evitar introducir carácteres**
       return /^[a-z0-9áéíóúüñ]*$/i.test(value);
         **validación de carácteres**
        }, "Ingrese sólo letras, números o espacios.");
           $("form[name='validFormulario']").validate({
        rules: {
         **nombre de los campos**
          nombre: {
               alfanumOespacio: true,
               required: true,
           },
          asunto: {
               required: true,
           },
          mensaje: {
               required: true,
           },
          correo: {
            required: true,
            correo: false
          },
        },
    **mensajes de validación**
        messages: {
          nombre: "<p style='color: red; font-family: arial; margin-left: inherit;'>Se Requiere LLenar Este Campo</p>",
          asunto: "<p style='color: red; font-family: arial; margin-left: inherit;'>Se Requiere LLenar Este Campo</p>",
          mensaje: "<p style='color: red; font-family: arial; margin-left: inherit;'>Se Requiere LLenar Este Campo</p>",
          correo: "<p style='color: red; font-family: arial; margin-left: inherit;'>Por Favor Ingrese Un Correo Válido</p>"
        },
     
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          form.submit();
        }
      });
    });
```

**este es mi formulario el cuál quiero validar pero al momento de dar click no hace nada y si lo cambio al submit si funciona**

```
<form method="post" name="validFormulario">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nombre"  id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo Electrónico">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="asunto" id="asunto" placeholder="Asunto">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea style="min-height: 150px; max-height: 300px;" class="form-control" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" rows="5" placeholder="Mensaje"></textarea>
            </div>
               **este es el boton tipo button el cual no funciona  **
            <div class="text-center"><input type="button" name="btn_EnviarCorreo" onclick="enviar();" value="Enviar Ahora"></div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Solo funciona con `submit` porque estás utilizando `submitHandler`. Al botón le faltaría el `id` y sin el `onClick`:

```
<input type="button" name="btn_EnviarCorreo" id="btn_EnviarCorreo" value="Enviar Ahora">
```

Como estás utilizando jQuery entonces llamas a la función `click` del botón:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btn_EnviarCorreo").click(function(){
        //Puedes hacer una prueba agregando un alert
        alert("click");
        //Agregas las validaciones de los campos
    }); 
});
```